# Помогите, пожалуйста, понять логику решения задачки

Tags: python-3.x, циклы

На берегу реки стояли n рыбаков, все они хотели перебраться на другой берег. Одна лодка может выдержать не более m килограмм, при этом в лодку помещается не более 2 человек. Определите, какое минимальное число лодок нужно, чтобы перевезти на другой берег всех рыбаков В первую строку вводится число m (1 ≤ m ≤ 10e6) - максимальная масса, которую может выдержать одна лодка. Во вторую строку вводится число n (1 ≤ n ≤ 100) - количество рыбаков. В следующие N строк вводится по одному числу Ai (1 ≤ Ai ≤ m) - вес каждого путешественника. Программа должна вывести одно число - минимальное количество лодок, необходимое для переправки всех рыбаков на противоположный берег.

Главная проблема у меня в цикле while: при запуске ошибка
weight.pop(t)
IndexError: pop index out of range

Я смог только в таком виде (см. код)

```
print("тоннаж: ")
m = int(input())
n = int(input("рыбаков: "))
boat = 0
weight =[]
if (n >= 1) and (n <= 100):
    print(f"вес: ")
    for i in range(n):
        a = int(input())
        if (a >= 1) and (a <= m):
            weight.append(a)
        else:
            print(f"превышен вес лодки: {m}.")
        
else:
    print("нарушено число рыбаков:  1 ≤ n ≤ 100.")
 
while len(weight):
    boat += 1
    for i in range(len(weight)):
        t = min(weight)
        if weight[i] + t <= m:
            weight.pop(i)
            weight.pop(t)
        else:
            weight.pop(i)
print(boat)
```

Comment: `t = min(weight)`  возвращает не индекс, а вес. А `pop` работает по индексу. Кроме того, удаление из списка внутри цикла по первоначальому размеру приведет к выходу за границу "гарантировано". Но прикидка алгоритма все равно некорректная, например при весах 10, 20, 70, 80 и 100-килограммовой лодке в первую попадут 10 и 20, и понадобятся 3 лодки, хотя достаточно двух. Думайте :)

Comment: `Если не знаешь, как решать задачу, отсортируй данные`- этот коан может помочь

Comment: @Alex Titov спасибо! примерно уловил мысль.

Comment: @MBo, понял, коаны люблю, спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

случайно нашел вашу задачу - как мне показалось она на backtracking
Я написал решение на javascript, но надеюсь будет понятно.
Вкратце этот перебор всех возможных вариантов, начиная с 1 и до лучшего. В худшем случае это будет О(b^n). Но так как, мы обрезаем некоторые ветви дерево, то получиться за O(n)
В функцию передаем кол-во лодок в виде массива, индекс для рекурсии, список рыбаков с весом, и максимальный вес для одной лодки.

Например

```
howManyFisherMans([0, 0], 0, [2, 5, 5, 6], 20)


function howManyFisherMans(boatsCandidates, index, weightFisherMans, weightOneBoat) {

if (weightFisherMans.length === index) return true;

for (let i = 0; i < boatsCandidates.length; i++) {
   if ( i > 0 && boatsCandidates[i - 1] === boatsCandidates[i]) continue; // оптимизация, для избежания зеркальной ветви в дереве
   if (boatsCandidates[i] + weightFisherMans[index] > weightOneBoat) continue;
      boatsCandidates[i] += weightFisherMans[index];
   if (howManyFisherMans(boatsCandidates, index + 1, weightFisherMans, weightOneBoat)) return true;
      boatsCandidates[i] -= weightFisherMans[index];
}
return false;
}

function countBoats(weight, fishersMen) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= fishersMen.length;i++) {
     if (howManyFisherMans(Array(i).fill(0), 0, fishersMen, weight)) return i;
  }         
}
```

countBoats - это клиентская функция, макс вес лодки и список рыбаков с весом.

**Нюанс, тут я не учитывал, что в лодку может помещаться макс. 2 рыбака, но это легко можно добавить еще один счетчик при захода в рекурсию**

Comment: Это слишком тяжёлое решение для такой задачи. Ограничение в два рыбака сильно всё упрощает - мы каждому (или не каждому) можем найти пару.

Comment: Поиск с возвратом не нужен. Задачу можно решить жадным алгоритмом, если рассмотреть лодку с самым тяжёлым рыбаком.